# MATLAB: Fastest Way to Count Unique # of 2 Number Combinations in a Vector of Integers

Tags: matlab

Given a vector of integers such as:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2]
```

I would like to find a really fast way to count the number of unique combinations with 2-elements.

In this case the two-number combinations are:

```
[1 2] (occurs twice)
[2 3] (occurs once) 
[3 4] (occurs once) 
[4 5] (occurs once) 
[5 1] (occurs once)
```

As it stands, I am currently doing this in MATLAB as follows

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2];
N = length(X)
X_max = max(X);
COUNTS = nan(X_max); %store as a X_max x X_max matrix

for i = 1:X_max

    first_number_indices   = find(X==1)
    second_number_indices = first_number_indices + 1;
    second_number_indices(second_number_indices>N) = [] %just in case last entry = 1
    second_number_vals = X(second_number_indices);

   for j = 1:X_max
        COUNTS(i,j) = sum(second_number_vals==j)
   end
end
```

Is there a faster/smarter way of doing this?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the application that I have in mind fo this is as follows: X is basically a sample path in a Markov Chain and COUNTS is a basic way to create the transition matrix so that after normalization, COUNTS(i,j) = P(next state = j | current state = i).

Comment: Good question, but I found the way you state it a bit misleading. You don't want to know the number of unique combinations, i.e. how many different combinations there are, but the number of occurrences of each combination. Otherwise, `unique(A, 'rows')` would have been your friend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a super fast way:

```
>> counts = sparse(x(1:end-1),x(2:end),1)
counts =
   (5,1)        1
   (1,2)        2
   (2,3)        1
   (3,4)        1
   (4,5)        1
```

You could convert to a full matrix simply as: `full(counts)`

---

Here is an equivalent solution using `accumarray`:

```
>> counts = accumarray([x(1:end-1);x(2:end)]', 1)
counts =
     0     2     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: haha, to be fair this sort of question comes up quite often (in relation to Markov chains), and the `sparse` solution is often cited :)

Comment: @Amro Can you think of a more elegant way to get the pairs/counts array in proper form than `[ii, jj] = find(counts); pairs = [ii, jj]; counts = full(diag(counts(ii, jj)));`

Comment: @EitanT: use all three outputs of find: `[ii,jj,v] = find(counts)`

Comment: @Amro I keep forgetting that `find` can return the elements themselves too :)

Comment: Very nice +1! What a great use of `sparse`. I'll use that myself in the future. But I assume it won't work if `X` contains zeros?

Comment: @ColinTBowers It would work, but you'll need to map the actual values to a set of unique indices, use `sparse` and count occurrences, then map the pairs back to the original values.

Comment: @ColinTBowers: yes as EitanT explained, for a more general solution, you'll need to map to integer indices using UNIQUE or GRP2IDX before calling SPARSE

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** @Amro has provided a much better solution (well, better in the vast majority of cases, I suspect my method would work better if `MaxX` is very large and `X` contains zeros - this is because the presence of zeros will rule out the use of `sparse` while a large `MaxX` will slow down the `accumarray` approach as it creates a matrix of size MaxX by MaxX).

**EDIT:** Thanks to @EitanT for pointing out an improvement that can be made using `accumarray`.

Here is how I would solve it:

```
%Generate some random data
T = 20;
MaxX = 3;
X = randi(MaxX, T, 1);

%Get the unique combinations and an index. Note, I am assuming X is a column vector.
[UniqueComb, ~, Ind] = unique([X(1:end-1), X(2:end)], 'rows');
NumComb = size(UniqueComb, 1);

%Count the number of occurrences of each combination
Count = accumarray(Ind, 1);
```

All unique sequential two element combinations are now stored in `UniqueComb`, while the corresponding counts for each unique combination are stored in `Count`.

Comment: `Count = accumarray(Ind, 1);` would probably be faster than counting with a loop. Also, you should indicate that X must be a column vector so that counting unique rows would work correctly.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks for that. I've incorporated the `accumarray` into my answer. Regarding the column vector issue, I've indicated in the in-code comments that `X` needs to be a column vector. Bit superfluous given Amro's fantastic `sparse` approach though :-)